# Moving a button to the right side of the screen

Tags: html, css, electron

I am trying to create a login window with a login form, but using a customized window with no frame, that I want to attach some custom buttons.
I have created the window with the top bar, with a single circle as a button, but trying to move it to the right seems impossible.
This is how it looks right now with the following code

HTML

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(48, 58, 65);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#controlBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(27, 42, 51)
}

#exit {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="knbn_login.css">

<body>

  <div id='controlBar' style='-webkit-app-region:drag'>
    <div id='exit'></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

What's the way to move it in the extreme right side of the window?
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `margin-left:auto` to the element like this :

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(48, 58, 65);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#controlBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(27, 42, 51)
}

#exit {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='controlBar' style='-webkit-app-region:drag'>
  <div id='exit'></div>
</div>
```

Or you can make it `inline-block` and use `text-align :right` on its container like this :

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(48, 58, 65);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#controlBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(27, 42, 51);
  text-align:right;
}

#exit {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='controlBar' style='-webkit-app-region:drag'>
  <div id='exit'></div>
</div>
```

Or use `float:right` like this :

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(48, 58, 65);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#controlBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(27, 42, 51);
}

#exit {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id='controlBar' style='-webkit-app-region:drag'>
  <div id='exit'></div>
</div>
```

Or `position:absolute` with `right:0` like this :

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(48, 58, 65);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#controlBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(27, 42, 51);
  position:relative;
}

#exit {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id='controlBar' style='-webkit-app-region:drag'>
  <div id='exit'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to `float` the element `right` using `float:right`

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(48, 58, 65);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

} 

#controlBar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(27, 42, 51)
}

#exit{
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="knbn_login.css">
    <body>

       <div id='controlBar' style='-webkit-app-region:drag'>
           <div id='exit'></div>
       </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```